# Translating algorithm/code from Ruby to PHP

Tags: php, ruby, encryption, hash, sha1

```
digest = HMAC.digest(Digest.new(SHA1), Base64.decode64(key), HashString) return Base64.encode64(digest.to_s()).chomp()
```

What would the above be in PHP?

Comment: Could you describe what this is supposed to do? Makes it much easier to decipher what you're trying to do (as opposed to looking up documentations). It might also simplify searching for you...

Comment: I'd have to agree with Franz, there are many functions for PHP that encrypt based off keys and hashes like mcrypt and whatnot, but there are often performance benefits based off of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$digest = hash_hmac("sha1", $hash_string, base64_decode($key), true);
return base64_encode($digest);
```